# Is this ODE solveable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It's quite possible neither of these 2 ODE's are solveable but I figured it was worth a shot to ask (in reality, I'm working with the SDE form of them but I wanted to try and see if the ODE form was solveable to get an idea for what the SDE should look like):

1) $dx(t) = \left[ \frac{\alpha(t)^2}{x(t)} - a(t)x(t) + b(t)  \right]dt$

2) $dN(t) = N(t)\left[b(t) - a(t)N(t) \right] dt$

In both cases, $a(t), b(t),$ and $\alpha(t)$ are all continuous bounded functions. I know in case 2, when a and b are fixed constants, the solution is given by:

$x(t) = \frac{b}{-a + e^{-bt}\frac{b+ax_0}{x_0}}$

(In reality, I want to work with $dN(t) = N(t)\left[\left(b(t) - a(t)N(t)\right) dt + \alpha(t)N(t)dW(t) \right]$, but it's probably better to first start with the ODE to get an idea for the solution).

For the first one, I was trying to get into the form of a Bernoulli Differential Equation, but that failed, so I'm wondering if it's even solveable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe #1 has closed-form solutions.  #2 does have solutions "by quadrature":

$$N \left( t \right) ={\frac {{{\rm e}^{\int \!b \left( t \right) 
\,{\rm d}t}}}{\int \!{{\rm e}^{\int \!b \left( t \right) \,{\rm d}t}}a
 \left( t \right) \,{\rm d}t+C}}
$$
This is because the substitution $u(t) = 1/N(t)$ yields a first-order linear equation.  I think you may like what it does to your SDE too.

Comment: Hmmmm perhaps I made a mistake. Using the substitution $u(t) = \frac{1}{N(t)}$ gives:

$dU = \frac{-1}{N^2}dN + \frac{d<N,N>}{N^3}$.  I'm still stuck with either an $N^{-1}$ or a $U^{-1}$

Comment: Ah, I guess that pesky extra term may mess things up on the SDE side.

Answer (score 0):

For 1), in fact this belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

In fact all Abel equation of the second kind can be transformed into Abel equation of the first kind.

Let $x(t)=\dfrac{1}{y(t)}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dx(t)}{dt}=-\dfrac{1}{y(t)^2}\dfrac{dy(t)}{dt}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{1}{y(t)^2}\dfrac{dy(t)}{dt}=\alpha(t)^2y(t)-\dfrac{a(t)}{y(t)}+b(t)$

$\dfrac{dy(t)}{dt}=-\alpha(t)^2y(t)^3-b(t)y(t)^2+a(t)y(t)$

Please follow the method in http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2